# Send a Map to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message

I've got a problem while sending a Map to a content script.

**the Map (key = value)** :

```
Forum depth = A.forumtitle
Forum title = LI.row A.forumtitle
Topic depth = A.topictitle
Topic title = LI.row.bg2 A.topictitle
Topic number of views = LI.row.bg2 DD.views
```

**background.js** :

```
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
     action: "scrap",
     data: levelsStructuresMap
  }, function (response) {});
```

**content.js** :

```
var levelsStructuresMap = message.data;
console.log("levelsStructuresMap : ");
for (var [key, value] of levelsStructuresMap) {
    console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

Here's the response from content :

> Error in event handler: TypeError: levelsStructuresMap is not iterable

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: [Messages must be JSON-serializable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). First make sure your map is.

Comment: A standard `Map` should be sent as `[...mapObject]` and recreated in the listener as `new Map(data)`

Comment: Oh yes I remember reading something about it a long time ago :) ! Since then I forgot about it ! Many thanks !

Comment: @wOxxOm : yes, it's less code so better :)